# Moving the <a id> tag before the <a href> tag

Tags: html, tags, grep, position, move

Position of  tag needs to come before the  tag. Have 500 instances I need to sort.

For example:

```
<h2 class="chapter-title"><a href="contents.html#Endnotes"><a id="Anchor"/>Endnotes and References</a></h2>
```

I am searching for

```
(<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*")([^"]+)("[^>]*>)(<a [^>]*id\s*=\s*")([^"]+)("[^>]*>)
```

to correctly pick up the two tags but am struggling on finding the right replace to correct the position.

Help!!???

Answer (score 2):

This worked to me:

```
$ sed 's#\(<a href[^>]*>\)\(<a id[^>]*>\)#\2\1#g' b
<h2 class="chapter-title"><a id="Anchor"/><a href="contents.html#Endnotes">Endnotes and References</a></h2>
```

We look for the text `<a href[^>]` and save it in the 1st var. Then we look for text `<a id[^>]` and save in the 2nd var. Finally we swap them.

Note that `<a id[^>]` means "everything starting from `<a id` and up to a `>` character.

Answer (score 0):

I this this should work. You only need two capture groups, one for the `<a href...>` and the other for `<a id...>`.

```
sed 's#\(<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*"[^"]+"[^>]*>\)\(<a [^>]*id\s*=\s*"[^"]+"[^>]*>\)#\2\1#'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, i think this should work

```
<a id="Anchor" href="contents.html#Endnotes">EndNotes and Refrences</a>
```